# Modify Routes.php file in cakephp

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I do not want to hardcode values in this page, instead I want to pick up values from database and set the main page.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index' ));
```

Instead of hard coded values of controller and action I want to fire a query on postgresql database and put those values in connect statement. But I cannot fire query in routes.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You can define dynamic routes in your **routes.php** like so:

```
  /**
   * Initialize model and perform find
   */
  $Route = ClassRegistry::init('Route'); 
  $routes = $Route->find('all'); 

  /**
   * Iterate over results and define routes
   */
  foreach ($routes as $route) {

    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => $route['Route']['controller'], 'action' => $route['Route']['action']));

  }
```

In this example, I'm using the **Route** model to create my routes. In reality, this could be any model of your choosing.

Comment: BTW, the example in my answer would send all my dynamic routes to the root URL. It was purely to show you how you could use the results of the find.

Comment: In which folder have you put Route model?

Comment: All models should live in the app/models/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, is to plug into your Routes model afterSave() callback and generate a cached version of the routes, something like (CakePHP2.0):

```
class Route extends AppModel {

    public function rebuildRouteCache() {

        $routes = $this->find('all')

        $routeCache = new File(CACHE . 'route_cache.php', true);

        $routeCache->write('<?php' . "\n");

        foreach($routes as $route) {

            $parsed = Router::parse($route['Route']['url']);

            $routeCache->write("Router::connect('" . $route['Route']['route'] . "', array('controller'=>'" . $parsed['controller'] . "', 'action'=>'" . $parsed['action'] . "', '" . $parsed['pass'][0] . "', 'plugin'=>'" . $parsed['plugin'] . "'));\n");
        }

        $routeCache->close();

        return true;

    }


    public function afterSave($created) {

        $this->rebuildRouteCache();
        return true;

    }

}
```

and add the following to app/Config/routes.php:

```
if (file_exists(CACHE . "route_cache.php")) {

    require CACHE . 'route_cache.php';

}
```

This way, the routes_cache.php file will only be updated when a route is saved, and you wont have the additional overhead of loading and reading the Route table on every page request.

Comment: Thanks, your code actually explained how to use Cake's file functions better than their documentation.