# URL redirection in CAKEPHP with database values

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I am working on a project based on cakephp. I just wanted to know How can I make a perfect URL redirection form database value. 
For example
I give here two current URLs and desired URLs

1.Current

```
/search?vendor=combo-training-certification-courses
```

1.Desired

```
combo-training-certification-courses
```

2.Current

```
/search?vendor=pmi-training-certification-courses
```

2.Desired

```
/pmi-training-certification-courses
```

Please tell me how can I achieve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add following code in config/routes.php

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
$Route = ClassRegistry::init('Vendor'); //MODEL NAME You can change it as your needs.
$routes = $Route->find('all');
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => $route['Route']['controller'], 'action' => $route['Route']['action']));
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138220/modify-routes-php-file-in-cakephp)